# Using Keycloak with groups storage federation (like user storage federation)

Tags: keycloak, federation

Currently we use Keycloak in our software with a custom federation plugin. This plugin fetches all users from our database and shows it within the keycloak admin itself. 
This works perfectly and is document well by Keycloak here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation

However what we also want be able to do is fetching groups from our  database and view it in Keycloak and add additional attributes and roles on Keycloak itself. So it should hold only a reference of the group on Keycloak (actually just like federated user storage).

After going through the documentation and the code I haven't found a solution yet.

Does anybody have an idea?